# Passing pointer by reference in C

Tags: c

Fairly new to c coding with background from c++. I have a simple program to sort an array using a function. I need to pass the int pointer by reference to the sort() function so that the compiler won't create a copy and after function call the array will be sorted. If I don't pass the reference, then after function ends the array will remain unsorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort(int* & arr, int s, int e)
{
  int temp = 0, i, j;
  for (i=0;i<e;i++)
  {
    for (j=i+1;j<e;j++)
    {
        if (*arr[i]>*arr[j])
        {
            temp = *arr[i];
            *arr[i] = *arr[j];
            *arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
  } 
}

int main()
{   
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    int i;

     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
         arr[i] = i+1;
     printf("Array before sorting:\n");
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
         printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
     printf("\n");

     sort(arr, 0, 10);
     printf("Array after sorting:\n");
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
         printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
     printf("\n");

     return 0;
}
```

I have also come to know that c doesn't allow pass by reference in a function, so how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why would you need to pass `arr` by reference? You never change it.

Comment: Pointers and arrays don't work the way you think they work. Pointers are not arrays. When you copy a pointer, an array is not copied. There is no harm in copying the pointer. You don't need to pass anything "by reference" here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, pass by reference is emulated by passing a pointer to the desired type.  That means if you have an `int *` that you want to pass to a function that can be modified (i.e. a change to the `int *` is visible in the caller), then the function should accept an `int **`.

In your specific case however, this isn't what you want.  You only need to pass an `int *` to your function which it can then dereference implicitly via the `[]` operator and change the elements of the array.

```
void sort(int *arr, int s, int e)
{
  int temp = 0, i, j;
  for (i=0;i<e;i++)
  {
    for (j=i+1;j<e;j++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>arr[j])
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as reference in C.

Passing a pointer to a function will not copy the object that the pointer is pointing to.

```
void foo(int* array);
```

You can then access the elements by deferencing the pointer.

```
int a = *array; //dereferencing the pointer. Getting the first element.
int b = array[0]; // does the same thing.
int c = *(array + 1) // second element. Pointer shifts by 1 * sizeof(type) bytes
int d = array[1] // second element again
```

Passing a pointer like this has the same overhead as passing an integer with the word size(since pointers are just integers underneath).

If you want to pass a pointer to an array you should pass it as a double pointer `**`. This will almost act as passing it as reference since you can change the pointer in the function.
Use case:

```
void foo(int** array) // passing a double pointer
{
    //....
    *array = theNewCollection;
    //...
}
```

Calling this function should be done as.

```
int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
foo(&arr);
```